# Selecting Percentile curves using gamlss::lms in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, percentile, gamlss

I am using example code from gamlss package to draw percentile curves:

```
library(gamlss) 
data(abdom)
lms(y,x , data=abdom, n.cyc=30)
```

[image]

It is drawing its own set of percentile curves. How can I choose to draw only 10th, 50th and 90th percentile curves? Also I want to avoid plotting of points so that only curves are drawn.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's always a good idea to read the help pages:

```
> centiles(h,xvar=abdom$x, cent=c(10,50,90), points=FALSE)
% of cases below  10 centile is  8.688525 
% of cases below  50 centile is  50.16393 
% of cases below  90 centile is  90
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my related question also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27507448/getting-percentile-values-from-gamlss-centile-curves