# Getting percentile values from gamlss centile curves

Tags: r, curve-fitting, percentile, gamlss

This question is related to: [Selecting Percentile curves using gamlss::lms in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27497068/selecting-percentile-curves-using-gamlsslms-in-r)

I can get centile curve from following data and code:

```
age = sample(5:15, 500, replace=T) 
yvar = rnorm(500, age, 20)
mydata = data.frame(age, yvar)
head(mydata)
  age      yvar
1  12  13.12974
2  14 -18.97290
3  10  42.11045
4  12  27.89088
5  11  48.03861
6   5  24.68591

h = lms(yvar, age , data=mydata, n.cyc=30)
centiles(h,xvar=mydata$age, cent=c(90), points=FALSE)
```

[image]

How can I now get yvar on the curve for each of x value (5:15) which would represent 90th percentiles for data after smoothening?

I tried to read help pages and found fitted(h) and fv(h) to get fitted values for entire data. But how to get values for each age level at 90th centile curve level? Thanks for your help.

Edit: Following figure show what I need:

[image]

I tried following but it is correct since value are incorrect:

```
mydata$fitted = fitted(h)
aggregate(fitted~age, mydata, function(x) quantile(x,.9))
   age    fitted
1    5  6.459680
2    6  6.280579
3    7  6.290599
4    8  6.556999
5    9  7.048602
6   10  7.817276
7   11  8.931219
8   12 10.388048
9   13 12.138104
10  14 14.106250
11  15 16.125688
```

The values are very different from 90th quantile directly from data:

```
> aggregate(yvar~age, mydata, function(x) quantile(x,.9))
   age     yvar
1    5 39.22938
2    6 35.69294
3    7 25.40390
4    8 26.20388
5    9 29.07670
6   10 32.43151
7   11 24.96861
8   12 37.98292
9   13 28.28686
10  14 43.33678
11  15 44.46269
```

Comment: I'm confused by the question. You already have displayed a result that I would have said represented your requested outcome.

Comment: I need the numbers to make a table of 90th percentile for each age (5:15). This cannot be aggregate(yvar~age,mydata,function(x)quantile(x, 0.9)) since above curve is a smooth version of those actual percentile values. I have added a figure to show the value that I need.

Comment: After looking at the documentation in multiple places, it looks to me that one would need to hack the `centiles` function. I believe the lines that do the work are: `ll <- eval(newcall); 
        if (plot) {
            lines(oxvar, ll, col = col.centiles[ii], lty = lty.centiles[ii], 
                lwd = lwd.centiles[ii], ...)`. So you would need to return the values of `ll` and either the `oxvar` values or recover the ordered xvar values.

Comment: I was trying a solution which I have added to my question above. Will that be correct?

Comment: I'd say it would not be your desired result. The `fitted` value of the `h`-object is the local mean. I wouldn't expect it to reflect the sampling variation. and so only if you also recovered the estimate for `sigma` could you construct an upper quantile estimate.

Comment: Yes, I saw they are all means. There are many sigma vectors in h (see output of command: str(h) ), including "sigma.fv". Which one should I use and how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this makes sense. The 90th percentile of a normal distribution with mean and sd of 'smn' and 'ssd' is `qnorm(.9, smn, ssd)`:  So this seems to deliver (somewhat) sensible results, albeit not the full hack of `centiles` that I suggested:

```
 plot(h$xvar, qnorm(.9, fitted(h), h$sigma.fv))
```

(Note the massive overplotting from only a few distinct xvars but 500 points. Ande you may want to set the ylim so that the full range can be appreciated.)

[image]

The caveat here is that you need to check the other parts of the model to see if it is really just an ordinary Normal model. In this case it seems to be:

```
> h$mu.formula
y ~ pb(x)
<environment: 0x10275cfb8>
> h$sigma.formula
~1
<environment: 0x10275cfb8>
> h$nu.formula
NULL
> h$tau.formula
NULL
```

So the model is just mean-estimate with a fixed-variance  (the `~1`) across the range of the `xvar`, and there are no complications from higher order parameters like a Box-Cox model. (And I'm unable to explain why this is not the same as the plotted centiles. For that you probably need to correspond with the package authors.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to create charts (similar to growth charts) for children of ages 5:15 for a health variable which is non-negative, continuous and in the range of 50-150 (with a few values outside this range). I have to create 90th, 95th and 99th percentile curves and also create tables for these percentiles. Is gamlss used as above the best method or should I use some other method in R? The sample size is about 8000.

Comment: I think you have now crossed over into the "please give me statistical advice"-territory which is better addressed on CrossValidated.com or as I suggested above to the package authors. You are welcome to cite this exchange. I'd be interested in what the real statisticians have up their sleeves.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. I appreciate your time and help. I will post this at crossvalidated and let you know their comments.